# Isometry in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: geometry

Is there an isometry on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that transforms the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} S(0,1/n)\cup\lbrace 0\rbrace\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to  $\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} S(n,1/n)\cup\lbrace 0\rbrace$ and leaves every thing else invariant? By $S(x,1/n)$ I mean the sphere of center $x$ and radius $1/n$.

Comment: What do you mean by $S(0,\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: Sorry! I explained.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean by $S(x, r)$ the sphere centered in $x$ of radius $r$.
If so, the answer is: No, there isn't.

Suppose there is an isometry $h$ that satisfies the two conditions. When you apply the inverse $h^{-1}$ on an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it will transform it to the unit sphere, but it leaves an element $x$ outside but arbitrarily close to the sphere $S(n,1/n)$ invariant. Take $n$ arbitrarily big and it's easy to show that the distance is not preserved ($n$ and $x$ can be chosen such that $d(n, x) = 1/n + \epsilon < 1$ and $d(h^{-1}(n), h^{-1}(x)) > n-1$). Contradiction.

I can explain further if you still have trouble understanding it.